# Mailing Server - what you recommend ? (will send 200,000 per month)

Tags: server, apache2, email, postfix, mailman

i need your recommendation for mailing server that will be send 200,000 emails per mount (don't worry this are customers that want to receive those emails)
i searching for mail server that can provide statistics (if the emails reach and read) 
i heard about "Mailman" 
what do you recommend ? 
thanks a lot 
Oren

Comment: I highly recommend a thrid party service. Here is a small list (pretty sure there are more though), Amazon SES, Elastic Email, Mailgun, Mandrill, Postage, Postmark, SendGrid. Check which best suits your need, based on pricing, limitation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend postfix, but if you are looking for perfect collaboration suite. Take a look Zimbra open source.

Regards